Windows server TLS versions
We have server 2019, and no keys created on:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols

This means that my server only can use TLS 1.2, right?

According to this documentation by default TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 are enabled in Windows Server 2019. TLS 1.3 is only supported in Server 2022 and newer versions.
Further this documentation states that TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are only disabled by default starting with Windows 11 (and Server 2022 i guess) in 2024.

If keys doesnt exist im not sure if you can use TLS 1.0 for example, this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-10-11-deprecation-in-windows says that you must create the keys to use it.

Yes. Starting with Windows 11 Insiders Preview and Windows Server Insiders Preview releases in 2024. Not Server 2019.

OK, i need to be sure that 1.0 and 1.1 dont work. Im going to create the keys to disabled it. Thanks
